# Why are the most recent posts not appearing in a fetch request, unless I'm logged in?

Tags: ajax, rest-api, cache

A live site, using a custom theme, has recently developed an issue: recent CPTs are not being pulled through when using a JavaScript fetch request — unless I'm logged into WordPress itself. The fetch request URL takes the form: `[domain]/wp-json/wp/v2/events?per_page=100&page=1&_fields=[custom_fields]`

I'm not 100% certain, but I *believe* this started when I started using filemtime for css/js cache busting. This seems to be only part of the issue though, as the posts are all fetched when I'm logged into WP. But as soon as I test in a private browser, any posts added within about the last 24hours are omitted.

Why could this be happening?

The site is using WordPress version 6.1.1.

(I know this is all rather vague, hence the lack of code, but I can happily provide any on request.)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is due to SiteGround caching data, in particular its Dynamic Cache. According to their [docs on Dynamic Cache](https://www.siteground.co.uk/kb/siteground-dynamic-caching-configuration/), they will "... monitor whether your browser has these cookies and bypass the cache if they are present".

One of the cookies they check against is **wordpress_logged_in_**, which explains the behaviour I described. When I flushed this cache manually, the new posts were fetched as desired.

It's unclear whether this has anything to do with filemtime, perhaps it's  mere coincidence.

I tried searching for ways to programmatically purge the Dynamic Cache (on post save hooks, for example), but couldn't find any useful information. So, the easiest solution by far was to install [the SiteGround CachePress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sg-cachepress/), which takes care of all cache types that can be found in the SiteGround site tools.